# Result from sqlite-3 DB does not push to Javascript array

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, node-sqlite3

I am working with a **NodeJS** application which fetches *film names and description* from an Sqlite-3 file when user send a `GET` to `/films`. There seems to be a thing which I am missing while pushing the object to an array. I don't get what I am missing. The object does not get pushed to the array and always shows empty [] when I `res.json()` it back as response.

```
app.get('/films', (req, res) => {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,  err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err.message)
        console.log('DB connected')
    })
    
    var films = []
    db.serialize(() => {
        db.each('select * from film', (err, row) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err.message)
            // console.log(row.name + '\t' + row.description)
            films.push({
                "name": row.name,
                "description": row.description
            })
        })
    })
    res.json(films)
    
    db.close(err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err.message)
        console.log('DB coonnection closed')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that Express returns response object before the database retrieves any values. To fix this you’d normally move it inside the callback function.

In your case though `db.each()` method actually accepts 2 functions. The 1st one is `callback` which runs after each value is retrieved and wouldn’t be any help at all. The 2nd one is called `complete` in documentation and does exactly what you need.

Here’s the [full reference in docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) for `db.each()` from `node-sqlite3` wiki.

With that you could write your code this way:

```
db.each(
  'select * from film',
  (err, row) => { /* Does normal stuff */ }),
  (err, num) => { /* Sends response to client */
    res.json(films);
    console.log(`Retrieved ${num} films`); // (Just to show what the 2nd argument does)
  }
);
```

Keep in mind that if your film database is not particularly huge docs actually recommend to use `db.all` method instead.

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. I just moved the response method in the `complete` part so the response is sent only after films array is completely created. Yes, `db.all` could also be used, but I wanted to do some manipulation with the fetched data before i could send the response. That's why I am using `db.each`.